# How I can make an application with irregular borders?

Tags: javascript, python, html, windows, frameworks

I'm trying to make a desktop application that looks like from a sci-fi movie but I'm having problems with the window form and I don't know what language or framework would allow me do this.

It would be great if I could do it with python or javascript "electron" but I think it isn't possible, so any other language, framework or whatever will be ok.

Here's an example of what I want.

[sci-fi ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbGp8.jpg)

Comment: you have to search information how to create normal window but without border and with transparent background. And then you can draw bitmap with irregular border. Many GUIs in most languages should have this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with Python and Javascript but I couldn't find anything relevant. I don't know if it is possible with any Microsoft's tool, I haven't used them for almost 10 years.